# Java - Access method in every classes and packages

Tags: java, package

I wrote a method `public static String timestamp()` in a class called `Utilities`, which I want to call in every `System.out.println()`.

Can you tell me how I can call this method in a different package? For example when I have `package XY`, with the class `XY` in it, then I can't call the `timestamp()` method, which is in the root src folder.

Comment: It should be mentioned that logging frameworks do just that and in a flexible manner.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the whole class name, so as your class is called "Utilities":

```
Utilities.timestamp();
```

Will call your method. Remember to import your "Utilities" class at the top of your calling class.

Alternatively, if you want to just call:

```
timestamp();
```

You can statically import the class:

```
import static com.foo.Utilities
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the package containing the class containing the `timestamp()` method. If you haven't declared a package for the class, you should do it now. After importing you can just use `Utilities.timestamp()` to call it.

If you're unfamiliar with packages in general, you should see the Oracle tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/

Comment: "If you haven't declared a package for the class, you should do it now."

Comment: Indeed! You can't use classes in a default package at all inside other packages, so you should definitely do so :)

Answer (score 0):

It's static so you can just call `Utilities.timestamp();`

Comment: @fallso beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

So, more often than not, utility classes are declared as `static`. I'll give you an example.

**Example**

```
public class Utilities
{
    public static String timestamp()
    {
          // Return timestamp.
    }
}
```

Then in your `XY` class, you need to `import` your `Utilities` class, and you can access it as follows.

```
Utilities.timestamp();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call it using:

```
Utilities.timestamp();
```

from any class. Remember to import the Utilities class